# Typescript compilation error with generic type and keyof

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I get a compilation error on the following code:

```js
class MyClass<T extends { [key: string]: string }> {
  private map = new Map<string, number>();

  get(key: keyof T): number {
    return this.map.get(key);
    //                  ^
    //       [E] Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable 
    //           to parameter of type 'string'.
    //           Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  }
}
```

The compiler doesn't see that I have a "string" constraint on the key of `T`...

And sure enough, when I try to do:

```js
const c = new MyClass<{ 1: 'asdf' }>();
```

It works without problem, even though I would expect it to tell me that the key `1` is of the wrong type.

Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: String index signatures accept numeric and symbol keys, as per [ms/TS#23592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592).  You can't really prevent them (e.g., `{1: "asdf"}` and `{"1": "asdf"}` are the same type); if you want to disallow non-`string` inputs for `get()` you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5Q9ZN), as recommended in the comments of ms/TS#23592. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find an appropriate dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep, that solved my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) in TypeScript does not really mean that the keys can only be `string`s.   Numeric keys (and even `symbol` keys) are allowed.

TypeScript has always had some ambiguity around what a "numeric" key is.  Technically JavaScript only supports `string` (and `symbol`) keys, and if you use a `number` it will be coerced to a `string`.  TypeScript allows numeric keys because this is a common use case, especially for array indexing.  That means, for key types, TypeScript sometimes treats numbers as if they were a special type of string:

```
let x: { 0: string } = { "0": "abc" }; // okay
x["0"] = "def";
console.log(x[0]) // "def"

let y: { "0": string } = { 0: "abc" }; // okay
y["0"] = "def";
console.log(y[0]) // "def"
```

Since TypeScript 2.9, the language has supported [non-`string` properties in mapped types and `keyof` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#23592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592).  So:

> If `X` contains a string index signature, `keyof X` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `string`, `number`, and the literal types representing `symbol`-like properties.

So `keyof { [key: string]: string }` is `string | number`.

---

Furthermore, when you have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an object type, it can always have *more* keys than mentioned in the constraint.  So `T extends U` doesn't mean that `keyof T` is constrained to `keyof U`, but can be any `string | number | symbol` at all.  Otherwise you couldn't do this, which is pretty basic functionality:

```
interface Foo { a: string }
function f<T extends Foo>(foo: T) {
  console.log(foo.a.toUpperCase());
  return foo;
}

interface Bar extends Foo { b: number };
const b: Bar = { a: "abc", b: 123 };
const result = f(b); // okay
// function f<Bar>(foo: Bar): Bar
console.log(result.b.toFixed(2)); // okay
```

Here `Bar` is constrained to `Foo`, but `keyof Bar` is not constrained to `keyof Foo`.

That means when you have `T extends { [key: string]: string }`, the keys of `T` are completely unconstrained.  Inside the body of your class, you will need to account for the possibility that `keyof T` includes `number` or `string`.

---

If you want to confine `get()`'s parameter to be just those keys of `T` which are `string`s, then you can use either `Extract<keyof T, string>` (via the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)
utility type)

```
get(key: Extract<keyof T, string>): number | undefined {
  return this.map.get(key); // okay
}
```

or `string & keyof T` (via an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), as suggested [in a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#23594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592#issuecomment-390876004)):

```
get(key: string & keyof T): number | undefined {
  return this.map.get(key); // okay
}
```

Either way should only allow you to use known string keys:

```
const s = Symbol("s");
const c = new MyClass<{
  a: string,
  b: string,
  123: "abc",
  [s]: number
}>(); // okay
c.get("a"); // okay
c.get(123); // error
c.get("b"); // okay
c.get(s); // error
c.get("c"); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDeEAMcDOYBOBLAdgcwgF8IBeBCAIiQrgoEMAjAYwqIG4IB6TiAewGs6ATwBQUANpUKAXVKUAJiABmFNiKa8cqXqAB0wXngAUEpNICUXHhUUqRI0JCFxEUtJlwFiZRCkqMWdis+QVEhSWpZMhtlVXVNbT0DY3CzS24FWPtcMBAMJTomEAgAMV5ecjp3bHwiESUAVxwmMCxNCCUAHgAVCBAoXJx5VFLygD4jJXK4bst4EQgIDS0dEH1DSfLdOl0wXgBVAAdDvIBhOlQQI3NzNUWMcAaMHA7ytUIRHLyCoogAIToGD6AxAQxGZQqiAYcBwDQAtgw8ux4lpIND-oC5Igqv5mBQADQQdEARgATABmZHLdAQB6oBrASBkJRGBi3YICYT4kQZRrNVrtLoAjATKa8ODC8wSwEoxJrZJGOkMsC6Bi7XglLBQEDyIykm4cDKc0TqYAXEYAWSEpzNqFQPWBg2G5HE-BAzgg6BqeGk1U8RDGCAWEEO2AAbnRchA4XRDnIcCAAO4QC2xzpezyE2EIvITW72RZ4cBGN0ejO1ABkEFLvCUEFmMPhiKBAB8IE1bLgdUHFvdHs8IGAABZYVC6GOHXRFsAl93so2hYMfYPT0mzj0AUQGGEKYE6Nbr3UJ5bwYylEGzzYgbY7yi78h7vYeYCeL2Ho-HsanxdL854xqXERl2pSARjIABlIQER0IwKFQCh8xApZ4yTFNrVte15kWHET25RZ0Vw4MyXJWgAgJYNxFQX0LybPIgLzQ1-0XJhvxnegEMYkJhHUVijGIv8+gwDBeAwHjp1ghgOI5ZjeNQAS8mE0SWPEigWHkoSRPsIA_)